# How to build a mesh from a line renderer drawing?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, line, mesh, game-development

I want a user to be able to draw a shape (let's say a non-perfect circle) using the line renderer with a cursor. Upon closing the loop to create the circle, I want to instantly build a mesh from the drawing. How can I accomplish this? View the image I attached for reference.[image: line render circle]

If these are the points included with a line renderer, how do I go about connecting the vertices and triangles to build the mesh? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For convex shapes (like in the picture), the easiest might be to calculate the "center point" (the center of gravity) of the shape and then just create a triangle strip using that point. let C = center-point and a[0]...a[N-1] be the points on the line, the first triangle would be a[0], C, a[1] etc.

Comment: Had to do something similar for my project. Check out http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Triangulator which turns 2D points into a 3D mesh, as well as this extruder of 2D points https://forum.unity.com/threads/trying-extrude-a-2d-polygon-to-create-a-mesh.102629/ (My result is shown at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IZw3-yiZvjQ )

Comment: @BitTickler that could work. Do you have an algorithm for calculating the center point of a convex shape?

Comment: https://answers.unity.com/questions/935437/find-center-point-of-regular-polygon.html This function from Bunny83 works relatively well for finding the center

Comment: The algorithm is called "average": `xm = Sum(a[0].x...a[N-1].x) / N` and respectively for y coordinate.